# Xamarin Forms UWP start application with parameters

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I have a Xamarin project (Droid and UWP(Fall Creators)) and 
I would like to start the UWP application by passing parameters.

I found how to start the application from command :

```
 explorer.exe shell:AppsFolder\TestCommand_7ngdmc6chkqa8!App
```

Now I am looking to add parameters.
I found some examples for UWP but it doesnt work with Xamarin.

Has anyone ever tried and found a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command line  `explorer.exe shell:AppsFolder\TestCommand_7ngdmc6chkqa8!App` could not be used to  launch UWP app with parameter. Windows Store apps aren't designed to run from the command line and there isn't a straightforward way to launch them from the command line. Although you can find some blogs about the above command line, but we could not recommend that.

Currently, It is a better way that launch UWP app with [`Windows.System.Launcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher) APi. But you need to register the protocol for your app at first.

After registered the protocol, you could also launch the App in the command prompt.

```
start [protocol name]:[parameter]
```

**Example**

```
start microsoft-edge:http://www.google.com
```

For more you could refer [Launch an app for results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-launch-an-app-for-results).